# PhpStorm project and network share

Tags: phpstorm, xdebug, remote-server, network-share

I need to debug a remote server and I setup a PhpStorm project based on a Shared Folder on the server.

The problem is that the project on the server is 13 GB in size and PhpStorm start downloading the files.

Is there a way to debug with Xdebug without downloading the files and use a network share? Not allowed to use SSH as there are many tutorials.

Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: 1) You can open the project via network mapped drive/share even though it's not really supported/recommended (as the IDE wants fast access to project files and networks adds that big latency as compared to SSD or even HDD). But the IDE still needs to index all project files. So it will be reading all of them and checking for a possible changes on the next session.

Comment: 2) The IDE needs the file where you have PHP breakpoint if you want to use Xdebug integration. It needs to know how to map local file (path in the project) to the actual remote location. Perhaps you can just download only needed set of files (needed to debug) and make a project from those files only. If it's a large project I would go this way.

Comment: good LazyOne , i understand what you mean... so i can downloand only executables, not images, css etc... ? only php ?

Comment: Yes. You can make a ZIP file on your remote server with only needed files (PHP + composer) -- ignore all CSS/HTML/JS/images etc, then download it here and extract into some folder. Then just launch the IDE, use "Open" and point to the root folder -- the IDE will make a project from those files. You can then set up the rest (Deployment etc).

Comment: Or you can try making a new project using that New Project wizard from existing files on your server and mark unwanted folders as Excluded / not to be downloaded. But I'm just not sure how well it woks (as I personally never use it this way -- it had some issues in the past / takes time to download multiple individual files as compared to one big ZIP)